# Bigquery- problem with the combination of insert into and 2 level order by

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, standards

I'm trying to update a table using **insert into**
the data I want to enter includes two levels of order by.
for some reason after the run the target table includes only the first level of the order by.
the order work perfectly when I run the query without the insert into part.
any thoughts?

to demonstrate my query:

insert into table_b
select * from table_a order by column_a , column_b desc

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean in the bigquery preview of table_b, the records does not show up in the order you want?

The preview of table_b, is not necessary in the order of your insert operations.

If you want to see records in table_b, in the order you want. you need to

```
select * from table_b order by column_a , column_b desc
```

Comment: I need the data ordered in the target table I'm updating, not just in the view, so select * won't help. This table will be pulled by an api/exported automatically to a csv  and the out come must be ranked. How can I garentee that?

Answer (score -1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as "ordering" in a SQL table unless a column specifies the ordering.

You have no control over the rows shown in the preview pane (well, they *might* come from the first partition on the table).  And if you do a `select * from t` with no `order by` the results are in an indeterminate order -- and that ordering might change each time you run the query.